# Workflow for grunt with multiple coffeescript file and a jQuery wrapper

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, gruntjs

My is a simple question, with grunt is possible compile a folder that contain *.coffee files in one file.
The problem in my case is add a wrapper for jquery or the classic domcontentloaded/ready dom in the file generated.
Actually the way for do that are two:

1. create a file like a.coffee and one z.coffee that contain the first part and last part of the wrapper and maintain an indentation in all the files
2. in every files add the wrapper

For a better workflow I think that if grunt can apply an unique wrapper is better.
What you suggest?

Asked by me also on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/coffeescript/comments/3zegd6/workflow_for_multiple_file_and_jquery_wrapper/

Answer (score 0):

I've written a bash script for that available on https://github.com/Mte90/Script/blob/master/coffeescript.sh

Use inotifywait as a watcher, merge the coffeescript files and generate also the sourcemap and contain a wrapper for jQuery.
In this way is not required to use grunt or gulp but only a simple script.